# Why does my game window not work in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, screen

i am trying to build a main menu in my app that then links you to the game, i have the game working the issue is that when you press play it takes you to the game that does not move however i used print statements to check and in fact the game is running in the background from the moment you start the app.

Here is the Py Code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix import label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout





class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    def StartUp(self):
        self.current = "Menu"
    pass


class MenuWindow(Screen):
    pass 

class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_y= NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_x= NumericProperty(0)

    velocity=ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x,velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(self.velocity) +self.pos



class PongPad(Widget):

    score=NumericProperty(0)

    def Check_bounce(self,ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball)   :
            vx,vy= ball.velocity
            bounced= Vector(-1* vx, vy )
            speedup= abs(((ball.velocity_x *0.1) -(ball.center_y - self.center_y)) *0.002) 
            vel = bounced *  (speedup +1.1)
            offset=(((ball.center_y - self.center_y)/2) - (ball.velocity_x /2)) *0.1
            if (ball.center_y - self.center_y) > 0:
                ball.velocity=vel.x,vel.y
                ball.velocity_y= 2
            else:
                ball.velocity= vel.x,vel.y
                ball.velocity_y= -2


class Game(Screen):

    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player_1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player_2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self,vel=(1,0.5)):
        print("234Served")
        self.ball.velocity= vel
        self.ball.center = self.center


    def Check_Top_Bottom(self):
        #Check bottom collion
        if self.ball.y <0:
            self.ball.velocity_y= abs(self.ball.velocity_y)

        #Check top colision
        if self.ball.y+50> self.height:
            self.ball.velocity_y = -abs(self.ball.velocity_y)

    def Check_if_score(self):#Score
        if self.ball.x >self.width:
            self.player_1.score +=1
            self.serve_ball()
        if self.ball.x+50 <0:
            self.player_2.score += 1
            self.serve_ball()

    def update(self,dt):
        self.ball.move()
        self.Check_Top_Bottom()
        self.Check_if_score()
        self.player_1.Check_bounce(self.ball)
        self.player_2.Check_bounce(self.ball)
        print(WindowManager().children)


    def on_touch_move(self,touch):
        if touch.x > self.width/2:
            self.player_2.center_y = touch.y
        else:
            self.player_1.center_y= touch.y




kv= Builder.load_file("myMenu.kv")


class myMenuApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game=Game()
        print(WindowManager().current_screen)
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0/60.0)

        return game




if __name__ == "__main__":
    myMenuApp().run()
```

And here is the KV code:

```
WindowManager:
    MenuWindow:
    Game:

<MenuWindow>:
    name: "Menu"
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.2,0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.39,"y":0.75}
            text:"Play"
            on_release:
                app.root.current= "Game"
                root.manager.transition.direction= "left"
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.2,0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.39,"y":0.7}
            text:"Settings"
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.2,0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.39,"y":0.65}
            text:"High Score"
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.2,0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.39,"y":0.6}
            text:"Quit"

<PongBall>
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 50,50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size





<PongPad>
    size_hint: None, None
    size:25,150
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size

<Game>:
    name:"Game"
    ball: Pong_ball
    player_1: Player1
    player_2: Player2

    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.center_x -5,0
            size: 15,root.height

    PongPad:
        id: Player2
        pos:root.width-25,root.center_y-75

    PongPad:
        id: Player1
        pos:0,root.center_y-75

    PongBall:
        id: Pong_ball
        center: self.parent.center
```

I have tried without the Builder but pretty much same issue, i also tried calling the Screen Manager in the return functions but that just gives me a blank screen.

Another thing is i tried checking the current screen when on the main menu and it outputs "NONE"

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues:

- When you execute `print(WindowManager().current_screen)` you are creating a new `WindowManager` and printing its `current_screen`. That is unrelated to any `WindowManager` in your GUI.
- You are loading your `kv` file, which builds a GUI with a `WindowManager` that it returns. But you ignore that returned `WindowManager` and the `build()` method returns a `Game` instance, which becomes the root of your GUI (with no `WindowManager`).

You can use the `on_enter()` method of `Screen` to start the `Game` when it becomes the current `Screen`, like this:

```
class Game(Screen):

    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player_1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player_2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        # start the game
        self.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
```

And in the `build()` method of your `App`, just return the GUI that is build by the `Builder`:

```
class myMenuApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv
```